# Pytorch copy a neuron in a layer

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I am using pytorch 0.3.0. I'm trying to selectively copy a neuron and it's weights within the same layer, then replace the original neuron with an another set of weights. Here's my attempt at that:

```
reshaped_data2 = data2.unsqueeze(0)
new_layer_data = torch.cat([new_layer.data, reshaped_data2], dim=0)
new_layer_data[i] = data1
new_layer.data.copy_(new_layer_data)
```

First I unsqueezed `data2` to make it a `1*X` tensor instead of `0*X`.
Then I concatenate my layer's tensor with the reshaped `data2` along dimension 0.
I then replace the original `data2` located at index `i` with `data1`. 
Finally, I copy all of that into my layer.

The error I get is:

```
RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor size, expected tensor [10 x 128] and src [11 x 128] to have the same number of elements, but got 1280 and 1408 elements respectively at /Users/soumith/code/builder/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorCopy.c:86
```

If I do a simple assignment instead of copy I get

```
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (11) must match the existing size (10) at non-singleton dimension 1. at /Users/soumith/code/builder/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensor.c:309
```

I understand the error, but what is the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to create a new model with the correct size and pass in weights as default values. No dynamic expansion solution was found.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to replace a `10x128` tensor with a `11x128` tensor, which the model doesn't allow. Is `new_layer` initialised with the size `(11, 128)`?
If not, try creating your new layer with your desired size `(11, 128)` and then copy/assign your `new_layer_data`.

Comment: new_layer is initialized with `10x128` I modify it to become `11x128`. You're suggesting creating an entirely new layer object then copying the data in? Isn't that akin to what I'm doing since `torch.cat` returns a new object?

Comment: ```torch.cat``` does indeed return a new object, but simply assigning that to the originally ```(10, 128)``` layer doesn't seem to cut it, at least when you're using ```.data```. You might want to abandon that altogether and assign ```.weight``` and ```.bias``` instead. See this forum post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-change-manually-the-size-of-a-layer-without-breaking-autograd/32749

Comment: Will take a look thank you, though I notice it's a later version of pytorch. If you post a solution from that I can mark your answer as correct.